# Get data to SQL Server from Excel using stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures, export-to-excel

I am currently trying to do some read/write operations from a SQL Server stored procedure into a Excel file, but can't find a way to get around this error:

> Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)"

This is my code:

```
sp_configure 'show advenced options', 1;
reconfigure;
go

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
reconfigure;
go

use [myproject]
go

select * 
from openrowset('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 'Excel 16.0; Database=C:\myexcel.xlsx', [sheet1$]);
go
```

My versions are Excel 16.0 and OLEDB 16.0 (compatible)

I also closed the Excel before running the test

PS: I can't find any ways to write to the Excel on the internet, do you have any links I can follow?

Thanks

Comment: correct driver is `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` - in your string the `E` from `ACE` is missing

Comment: Is file on the same machine as the SQL Server instance you're trying to get data into?  C:\ is relative to the SQL Server instance here.

Comment: unfortunattly it do not come from this, I work on a computer that don't have internet, and I missed a key during the "manual" copy paste @Ike

Comment: yes it is @squillman, they both ar on the same machine

Comment: Also, does the SQL Server Service account have access to the root of C? It's *highly* unlikely it does.

Comment: where do you suggest the excel to be? (I also tried the desktop C:\users\me\desktop)

Comment: In a folder that the service account does have access to. That depends on what credentials said account is running under. If it's the default service account, it'll only have access to the installation directories.

Comment: Ok, after I tested it, I can tell my problem do not come from this, any other ideas?